# d3.js enter() not binding to data correctly - re-creating existing data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have an odd issue where the `enter()` selection fails to detect already existing elements. Every time I call `enter()` it re-creates the same elements, and doesn't delete any.

What's wrong?

```
clusters = [ 
{ "clusternumber": 9,  "value": "blah1"},
{ "clusternumber": 10, "value": "blah2"},
];

function redraw()
{
var cluster = clusterView.selectAll(".cluster")
                .data(clusters, function(d) {return d.clusternumber; });

//
// Clusters entering the view
//

var clusterEnter = cluster.enter()
                        .insert("div", ".cluster");

//
// Clusters to update
//

var clusterUpdate = d3.transition(cluster)
  .style("fill-opacity", 1);

//
// Clusters to remove
//

var clusterExit = d3.transition(cluster.exit())
    .style("fill-opacity", 0)
    .remove();

}
```

EDIT: JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dpdwbwck/): update() is called twice, and the DOM objects are generated twice. This must be something simple I'm overlooking!

EDIT: full code at http://maxhunter.me/clusterviewd3.html if you care...

Comment: Likely an issue with the way your clusters are initially built. Can you share the complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was something a bit silly:

```
.insert("div", ".cluster");
```

doesn't actually create a div in class `cluster`.

Replacing it with:

```
.insert("div")
.attr("class", "cluster")
```

solves the problem!